# $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) ≤ \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A, B ∈ M_{m×n}(F)$. Could someone give a hint as to how to prove that $$\operatorname{rank}(A + B) ≤ \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B).$$

Comment: Hint is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246941/prove-that-operatornameranka-operatornamerankb-ge-operatornamera?rq=1) here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rank of the difference of matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375982/rank-of-the-difference-of-matrices). Actually [Prove that $\def\rk{\operatorname {rank}}\rk (A)+\rk(B)\geq\rk(A+B)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246941) is better as duplicate

Answer (score 5):

You can view it in terms of linear maps associated to matrices. Let $f_A, f_B$ the linear maps associated to $A$ and $B$ in some fixed basis. Then, it suffices to prove that
$$\operatorname{Im}(f_A+f_B)\subseteq \operatorname{Im}(f_A)+\operatorname{Im}(f_B)$$
but this is clearly true, since

$$(f_A+f_B)(x)=f_A(x)+f_B(x)\in\operatorname{Im}(f_A)+\operatorname{Im}(f_B)$$
for every vector $x$.

Comment: What is $x$? How are the linear maps associated?

Comment: @YosefQian $x\in F^n$ and $f_A(x)=A\cdot x$ (matrix product)

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

1. $rank(A)=\dim\,im(A)=\dim\{Ax\,\mid\,x\in F^n\}$
2. $im(A+B)\subseteq im(A)+im(B)$
3. $\dim(U+V)\le\dim U+\dim V$.

Comment: How do you come to action 3.)?